# Why this react code requests data from server twice

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have this minimal code to fetch data from a server, but it requests data twice, what I'm doing wrong?

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import './App.css'
import axios from 'axios';

function App() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState(null);

  const getPosts = () => {
    axios.get('https://tamoudahost.com/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/posts').then((res) =>{
      setPosts(res.data)
    } )
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    !posts && getPosts()
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
        {posts && posts.map((post) => <div key={post.id}>{post.id} : {post.date}</div>)}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

I'm using vite

Comment: Are you using strict mode?

Comment: Do you mount `App` component twice?

Comment: try and use the console.log to see the data you are returning

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. @JBallin I'm using strict mode I guess and is not an option request, both are GET request, and I'm getting the same response